# switch statement doesn't rotate without menu

Tags: powershell, switch-statement

I am running the script below and when i execute the statement it runs all 3 of the statement at the same time so it goes back to the original location.

original code vv

```
fsutil reparsepoint query "d:/tf90/test" > outfile.txt



$path = Get-Content D:\tf90\outfile.txt | Select-Object -last 5 


$choice = @('1','2','3')

switch ($choice)
{
'1' {$path = ' 0000:  1a 00 22 00 00 00 1a 00  00 00 00 00 64 00 3a 00  ..".........d.:.
     0010:  5c 00 74 00 66 00 39 00  30 00 5c 00 74 00 65 00  \.t.f.9.0.\.t.e.
     0020:  73 00 74 00 31 00 5c 00  3f 00 3f 00 5c 00 64 00  s.t.1.\.?.?.\.d.
     0030:  3a 00 5c 00 74 00 66 00  39 00 30 00 5c 00 74 00  :.\.t.f.9.0.\.t.
     0040:  65 00 73 00 74 00 31 00                           e.s.t.1.'

 remove-item -force d:\tf90\test;

mklink test/d d:\tf90\test2 }

'2' {$path='
0000:  1a 00 22 00 00 00 1a 00  00 00 00 00 44 00 3a 00  ..".........D.:.
0010:  5c 00 74 00 66 00 39 00  30 00 5c 00 74 00 65 00  \.t.f.9.0.\.t.e.
0020:  73 00 74 00 32 00 5c 00  3f 00 3f 00 5c 00 44 00  s.t.2.\.?.?.\.D.
0030:  3a 00 5c 00 74 00 66 00  39 00 30 00 5c 00 74 00  :.\.t.f.9.0.\.t.
0040:  65 00 73 00 74 00 32 00                           e.s.t.2.'

 remove-item -force d:\tf90\test;

mklink test/d d:\tf90\test3 }

'3' {$path='0000:  1a 00 22 00 00 00 1a 00  00 00 00 00 44 00 3a 00  ..".........D.:.
0010:  5c 00 74 00 66 00 39 00  30 00 5c 00 74 00 65 00  \.t.f.9.0.\.t.e.
0020:  73 00 74 00 33 00 5c 00  3f 00 3f 00 5c 00 44 00  s.t.3.\.?.?.\.D.
0030:  3a 00 5c 00 74 00 66 00  39 00 30 00 5c 00 74 00  :.\.t.f.9.0.\.t.
0040:  65 00 73 00 74 00 33 00                           e.s.t.3. '
remove-item -force d:\tf90\test;

mklink test/d d:\tf90\test1 }
}
```

I have added a menu into the statement and it works but is not what i need to do automation.

new code---vvvv----

```
fsutil reparsepoint query "d:/tf90/test" > outfile.txt

Get-Content D:\tf90\outfile.txt | Select-Object -last 5 | Write-Host -ForegroundColor green

$path = Get-Content D:\tf90\outfile.txt | Select-Object -last 5 


$menu = ('1','2','3')
$choice = $Menu | Out-GridView -OutputMode Multiple -Title 'Select Locations you want to run staging, and click OK.'

switch ($choice)
{
'1' {$path = ' 0000:  1a 00 22 00 00 00 1a 00  00 00 00 00 64 00 3a 00  ..".........d.:.
     0010:  5c 00 74 00 66 00 39 00  30 00 5c 00 74 00 65 00  \.t.f.9.0.\.t.e.
     0020:  73 00 74 00 31 00 5c 00  3f 00 3f 00 5c 00 64 00  s.t.1.\.?.?.\.d.
     0030:  3a 00 5c 00 74 00 66 00  39 00 30 00 5c 00 74 00  :.\.t.f.9.0.\.t.
     0040:  65 00 73 00 74 00 31 00                           e.s.t.1.'

 remove-item -force d:\tf90\test;

mklink test/d d:\tf90\test2 }

'2' {$path='
0000:  1a 00 22 00 00 00 1a 00  00 00 00 00 44 00 3a 00  ..".........D.:.
0010:  5c 00 74 00 66 00 39 00  30 00 5c 00 74 00 65 00  \.t.f.9.0.\.t.e.
0020:  73 00 74 00 32 00 5c 00  3f 00 3f 00 5c 00 44 00  s.t.2.\.?.?.\.D.
0030:  3a 00 5c 00 74 00 66 00  39 00 30 00 5c 00 74 00  :.\.t.f.9.0.\.t.
0040:  65 00 73 00 74 00 32 00                           e.s.t.2.'

 remove-item -force d:\tf90\test;

mklink test/d d:\tf90\test3 }

'3' {if ($path='0000:  1a 00 22 00 00 00 1a 00  00 00 00 00 44 00 3a 00  ..".........D.:.
0010:  5c 00 74 00 66 00 39 00  30 00 5c 00 74 00 65 00  \.t.f.9.0.\.t.e.
0020:  73 00 74 00 33 00 5c 00  3f 00 3f 00 5c 00 44 00  s.t.3.\.?.?.\.D.
0030:  3a 00 5c 00 74 00 66 00  39 00 30 00 5c 00 74 00  :.\.t.f.9.0.\.t.
0040:  65 00 73 00 74 00 33 00                           e.s.t.3. ')
{remove-item -force d:\tf90\test;

mklink test/d d:\tf90\test1 }
}
}
```

I am trying to have the switch statement automatically use one of the choices and then execute it when the outfile is read. i need the output put into the `$path` and have the switch statement see what the output is and go to one of the choices to execute the commands the match the `$path`

Comment: "automatically use one of the choices" - yes, but which one? Should it just pick a random one?

Comment: it doesn't need to choose at random i need it to choose one that matchs the output and then execute.

Comment: What output? The output from Get-Content?

Comment: yes the output from get content

Comment: if get-content is the wrong thing for this please let me know so i can correct it

Comment: Ahh, you want to compare the reparsepoint query output with your `$path` variables.

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell 5.0:

PowerShell 5.0 adds support for reparsepoints in the filesystem provider:

```
$Link = Get-Item D:\tf90\test
$TargetFileName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($Link.Target)

switch($TargetFileName) {
    "test1" { # rotate to test2 }
    "test2" { # rotate to test3 }
    "test3" { # rotate to test1 }
}
```

## PowerShell 4.0 and earlier:

If you want to use a switch to compare the output from `fsutil` with a known string, you need to use that string as your choice item inside the switch.

To avoid having a five-line string for each possibility inside the switch body, store them in variables:

```
# run reparsepoint query
fsutil reparsepoint query "d:/tf90/test" > outfile.txt

# grab the relevant portion of the file
Write-Host ($ReparsePointPath = Get-Content D:\tf90\outfile.txt | Select-Object -Last 5) -ForegroundColor Green

# define the strings you want to compare it to
$Path1 = @'
0000:  1a 00 22 00 00 00 1a 00  00 00 00 00 64 00 3a 00  ..".........d.:.
0010:  5c 00 74 00 66 00 39 00  30 00 5c 00 74 00 65 00  \.t.f.9.0.\.t.e.
0020:  73 00 74 00 31 00 5c 00  3f 00 3f 00 5c 00 64 00  s.t.1.\.?.?.\.d.
0030:  3a 00 5c 00 74 00 66 00  39 00 30 00 5c 00 74 00  :.\.t.f.9.0.\.t.
0040:  65 00 73 00 74 00 31 00                           e.s.t.1.
'@
$Path2 = @'
0000:  1a 00 22 00 00 00 1a 00  00 00 00 00 44 00 3a 00  ..".........D.:.
0010:  5c 00 74 00 66 00 39 00  30 00 5c 00 74 00 65 00  \.t.f.9.0.\.t.e.
0020:  73 00 74 00 32 00 5c 00  3f 00 3f 00 5c 00 44 00  s.t.2.\.?.?.\.D.
0030:  3a 00 5c 00 74 00 66 00  39 00 30 00 5c 00 74 00  :.\.t.f.9.0.\.t.
0040:  65 00 73 00 74 00 32 00                           e.s.t.2.
'@
$Path3 = @'
0000:  1a 00 22 00 00 00 1a 00  00 00 00 00 44 00 3a 00  ..".........D.:.
0010:  5c 00 74 00 66 00 39 00  30 00 5c 00 74 00 65 00  \.t.f.9.0.\.t.e.
0020:  73 00 74 00 33 00 5c 00  3f 00 3f 00 5c 00 44 00  s.t.3.\.?.?.\.D.
0030:  3a 00 5c 00 74 00 66 00  39 00 30 00 5c 00 74 00  :.\.t.f.9.0.\.t.
0040:  65 00 73 00 74 00 33 00                           e.s.t.3.
'@

# Run the output through the switch
switch ($ReparsePointPath){
    $Path1 {
        Remove-Item -Force d:\tf90\test
        cmd /c mklink test/d d:\tf90\test2
    }

    $Path2 {
        Remove-Item -Force d:\tf90\test
        cmd /c mklink test/d d:\tf90\test3
    }

    $Path3 {
        Remove-Item -Force d:\tf90\test
        cmd /c mklink test/d d:\tf90\test1
    }
}
```

Comment: it is still doing the same thing that the original script was doing.

Comment: Only if one of the `$Path1`, `$Path2` or `$Path3` strings match the output exactly

Comment: the strings match the output but it still does all 3 of the switches

Comment: @bgrif you might want to do `$ReparsePoint = $ReparsePoint -join [Environment]::Newline` so that the switch value is also a string and not a string array